# How do I use JQuery to customize wheelnav tooltips

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, wheelnav.js

While going through the source code, I found a way to set tooltips for each navslice with `<piemenu>.navItems[i].tooltips = "<tooltip>"`

I would like to customize these tools tips with JQuery. However I can't find the documentation to do so.

If someone could help me out, or point me in the direction of wheelnav.js docs for tooltips. I'd be glad.

Comment: the correct syntax is wheel.navItems[i].tooltip = "<tooltip>"; there is no 's' at the end of tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in 2022.
Wheelnav generates a title tag inside a path element and it isn't customizable currently.

```
<path fill="#2d9e46" stroke="#111111" d="..." stroke-width="0" fill-opacity="1" id="wheelnav-wheelDiv-slice-0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: default; fill-opacity: 1;" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
    <title style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">TOOLTIP</title>
</path>
```